# copying packages from different projects to another project using maven

Tags: maven

i have different maven projects, i planning to create one more maven project in that i want to copy some packages from above projects. Can I do copy the packages from other projects to another project using maven ?

Comment: In Java, you don't copy packages. You reference the jars that contain these packages.

Comment: What previous commentator means -i think- is that with Maven the procedure is to add dependencies not copying packages or sources. Dependency or artifact is a jar (most often at least), a jar that is a result of packaging some project that contains these common packages.

Comment: Sorry for the late response as i was in different project now, @JFMeier, I have applied your suggestion.